# How to make graph or chart in asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a graph using database but i cannot access the values from database, an error is occurred during execution. And this is my code in cshtml.

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Database1");
    var data = db.Query("SELECT Name, price FROM Product");
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Product Sales")
        .DataBindTable(dataSource: data, xField: "Name")
        .Write();
}
```

This is the error when i run the application:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Note: Second line, about query, is highlighted during error.

Comment: Verify your Sql Connectionstring is right or not?

Comment: In keeping with the principles of MVC, querying data should not be done in a view, but rather a controller or service layer and that data should be passed to the view.

Comment: Look at the error message. It explains the problem and even tells you the first steps to take in fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more interactive and intuitive charts instead of the static chart images, check following library which is the .NET way to display Highcharts into your ASP.NET application.

Check this Highchart .Net Library
https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/

Comment: Do you have any experience with it?